# Paint to protect schedule 40 black steel pipe running outside above ground

Tags: paint, pipe, gas

Do I need to paint or otherwise protect black gas pipe running outside to the meter?
The existing pipe is painted gray, I imagine this is to prevent rust.
If paint is needed, is there a specific kind that is recommended?

I live near Denver if that affects the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you're painting metal, I would avoid latex paint (which is nearly every can of paint in the home-improvement store).

The #1 issue is paint prep, especially if there's rust.   Rust is very difficult to stop if it's underway under paint.  Any way you can remove it; sandblasting is not excessive.**   **Paints that claim you can paint over rust are lying**, sure, you can do it, but the rust will punch through in short order.

Then a good anti-rust primer (I've been surprised by the performance of plain old Rustoleum 7769 Rusty-Metal Primer, especially if the rust removal is less than perfect).   Then a quality oil paint.

Generally, *colors* will not hold up in hardware-store-priced paints, because mineral pigments like *lead chromate (shudder)* are illegal, and organic pigments that hold up are prohibitive ***.  Fortunately *carbon black* is a mineral pigment not toxic to humans, so you can get cheap good black paint. And that's a fine color for a "black pipe" gas pipe.

---

** In fact, in extensive testing by NASA (who owns more steel structures in corrosive environments than anyone in the world), sandblasting is proven to be the *only* method that really works, with significant performance gains over needle-scaling and heavy sanding/grinding.

*** To give you an idea, I normally use top quality LPU over epoxy primer. I'm used to paying $160/gal. for black or white (but mind you it covers 1000 square feet).  I ordered some burgundy, and it was $295/gal. because of the pigments.  I do not recommend using LPU over epoxy because the cost of initially getting set up in the primers, converters and other chemicals is north of $400, a bit extreme for a small job.

Answer (score 1):

@Harper. Right on the money with surface prep. Then an etch primer immediately after surface prep (within hours - a day is too long) and for seriously heavy duty a tar epoxy. There are zinc based 'galvanising paints' available and the grey paint you describe may be one. Ignore any advice that they are self-priming, it's kinda true but a separate primer coat will always give a better and more durable result.  Down side is that galvanising paint are not good in high wear areas. Do not attempt to treat or paint in damp / cold (less than 15°C) weather.